# Is it possible to link a shape key animation to only one of my actions?

Tags: animation, shape-keys

I have several actions(animations) for my character rig and in one of the animations I wanted to use a shape key to animate only part of the mesh.

I did complete the shape key animation but it shows up in all of my actions.

My question:
***Is it possible to link a shape key animation to only one of my actions?***

This will be exported as a character into Unity.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whilst trying to solve my problem I realized that there was a better way to do this and by using a ***driver bone*** to animate the shape key I could keep the shape key animation linked to only one of my actions.

If anyone else is had this same problem I would recommend looking up key shape drivers. It will save you a headache.

Comment: I am happy you could solve your own problem but I already have 20 animations ready that are suddenly ruined by this one shape key appearing in all of them. Is it viable for me at this point to create a driver bone? There must be another way

Comment: yes, i added a driver bone after i already had a bunch of animations so It should work. using a driver bone was the answer in my case.

Comment: Thank you so much for being willing to help. I created my bone in Blender 2.8 and am pleased that it doesn't move relative to the root. I need to figure out how to assign my existing shapekey-keys to the driver now (also: how to make this new bone a driver). This is the action that requires the shapekey: youtube.com/watch?v=eBQzJglA8Gs All others don't need it. I have another shapekey for just one action, too. I am thinking of setting it to the orientation of this one new bone/lever.